# Why does mypy say that my return type is incompatible (subset of union types)?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Why does mypy say that my return type is incompatible?
Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import typing
import dataclasses

import immutabledict

class Unset:
    pass

unset: Unset = Unset()

OUTPUT_BASE_TYPES = typing.Union[
    immutabledict.immutabledict[str, 'OUTPUT_BASE_TYPES'],
    str,
    int,
    float,
    bool,
    None,
    typing.Tuple['OUTPUT_BASE_TYPES', ...],
]

@dataclasses.dataclass
class ApiResponse:
    body: typing.Union[OUTPUT_BASE_TYPES, Unset] = unset


class MyDict(immutabledict.immutabledict[str, typing.Union[None, str]]):
    pass

@dataclasses.dataclass
class CustomApiResponse(ApiResponse):
    body: MyDict


inst = ApiResponse(body=1)
other_inst = CustomApiResponse(body=MyDict({}))
```

mypy reports:

`mypy union.py union.py:36: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "MyDict", base class "ApiResponse" defined the type as "Union[OUTPUT_BASE_TYPES, Unset]")  [assignment]`

But the definition of the values for immutabledict typing.Union[None, str] are a subset of the union of types OUTPUT_BASE_TYPES
so why is this failing?

How do i get it to work? What do I need to change?

#### mypy version

- Mypy version used: mypy 1.4.1 (compiled: yes)
- Mypy command-line flags: none, `mypy union.py`
- Mypy configuration options from `mypy.ini` N/A
- Python version used: Python 3.7.12 (default, Sep 20 2022, 17:18:51)
  [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin

Comment: I don't think mypy supports recursive types unitil more recent versions, what version are you on?  I know pyright does

Comment: just added the version info

Comment: I bet `immutabledict` is invariant in value type, and so `immutabledict[str, A | B]` is not a subtype of `immutabledict[str, A | B | C]`. It's a bug in their stubs - it is possible to make `immutabledict` behave covariantly (because it's immutable, yes). Consider reporting this to maintainers. They could have made [`_V` covariant](https://github.com/corenting/immutabledict/blob/master/immutabledict/__init__.py#L9).  To verify, just try to type check `x: immutabledict[str, int]; y: immutabledict[str, int | str] = x` . The issue is not related to recursive aliases.

Comment: Yup you are right, that was it. I filed an issue with them at https://github.com/corenting/immutabledict/issues/243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the immutabledict is not covariant but I expected it to be.

Immutable collections (Sequence/Tuple) [are covariant per mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generics).
Once I changed the _K TypeVar in immutabledict to `covariant=True` then my original code worked.